# GET request OkHTTP throws Exception

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I have GET request OkHTTP in android studio.

```
public class ReceiveMessage {
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .build();

public void getReceiveRequest(String user) {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("localhost:8080/tuk_tuk/4353453465")
            .method("GET", null)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            call.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            assert response.body() != null;
            Log.d("TAG",response.body().string());
        }
    });

}
```

}

I create object ReceiveMessege. Then I call method getReceiveRequest in MainActivity.
But i get Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5317)
    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:122)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21648)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5941)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:816)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5317) 
    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:122) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21648) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5941) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:816) 
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unexpected url: localhost:8080/tuk_tuk/4353453465
    at okhttp3.Request$Builder.url(Request.java:143)
    at com.mardaunt.telesupp.ReceiveMessage.getReceiveRequest(ReceiveMessage.java:23)
    at com.mardaunt.telesupp.MainActivity.onToggleAllMask(MainActivity.java:155)
```

P.S. Server returns String value - "Nothing"
Maybe do you know? How i can run a valid request?

Comment: Have you already tried formatting with `http://localhost.....` ?

Comment: Ohh... I am so sorry. Thats stupid of me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unexpected url: localhost:8080/tuk_tuk/4353453465
at okhttp3.Request$Builder.url(Request.java:143)
```

Uncorrect url format!